# Отправить POST через прокси-сервер вместе с cookie-jar, user-agent

Tags: golang

Как я знаю чтоб устанавливать хедеры типа `User-Agent, Content-Type` и т.д нужно создавать объект `http.NewRequest`, потом `url.Parse`, `&http.Client`. У меня есть код на метод `GET` без `Cookie`:

```golang
proxyUrl, err := url.Parse(proxy)
httpClient := &http.Client{Transport: &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}}
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", host, nil)
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", agent)
resp, err := httpClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
} else {
    //TODO
}
```

Какие нужно произвести манипуляция с POST-Запросом?
Как мне добавить `User-Agent`, отправить `Cookie-Jar` и отправить все через прокси POST-запросом под форму `url.Values`?

Answer (score 1):

Кодируете значения, создаёте запрос, устанавливаете заголовки, и отправляете:

```golang
values := url.Values{}
values.Add("name", "John Smith")
valuesR := strings.NewReader(values.Encode())

req, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, "http://127.0.0.1:8080", valuesR)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "foo")
req.AddCookie(&http.Cookie{
    Name:  "token",
    Value: "123",
})

resp, err := c.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: А как работать с cookieJar? Там же совсем все по другому

Comment: @JackAnderson Допишите в вопрос, что именно в использовании CookieJar вас смущает. CookieJar используется как правило чтобы сохранить куки между запросами.